# Why did South Africa retire its Atlas Cheetahs?

Tags: south-africa, dassault-mirage-iii

South Africa sold its Atlas Cheetahs to Equador and bought JAS39 Gripen from Sweden.

What was the reason for retiring those Cheetahs when a lot of nations are still using Mirage-3s and 5s?

South Africa has the capability to upgrade/build/rebuild its jets by itself.

So, why retire?

Comment: Nations using Mirage 3 s and 5s are not in the same tier as SA. Cheetahs became increasingly obsolete in comparison to international fighter aircraft. Saleable to lower-tier countries or for use as in "aggressor" training, like the old Hawker Hunters they use in USA.

Comment: Argentina retired Gloster Meteors in 1970.

Comment: The Cheetah was itself an upgrade of the Mirage 3's, a 1960's aircraft, that they already had, so you can imagine how obsolete they had become by the time they were retired. SA most likely retired them because the cost of maintenance was becoming prohibitive, parts were becoming impossible to find, and yet another upgrade made no sense.

Comment: This _might_ be on topic in [politics.se] as well.

Comment: Because airframes become obsolete.